# How to store level information on iOS

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios

Let's imagine I have a breakout game. I make a level like this:

```
For columns < max columns
    For rows < max rows
        Create sprite from file, put it on some position based on 
        current column and row, put it into array of objects.
```

Now, imagine I have 100 levels and I want them to be different. What tools should I use to ease my life? How do I load a level from file? Maybe a `plist`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any format that's convenient to you. `plist` works fine as you can easily parse it into data-structures without the need of external libraries. Also something like `JSON` or plain `CSV` would work. If you write a level-editor yourself, you can use any of these formats.

You don't have to write the level editor yourself though. Since your game is row/column based, a tile editor like [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) works just fine. [Cocos2d directly supports Tiled maps](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3atiled_maps). I guess any other tile-editor will work fine too.

If you don't like Tiled and rather wish to freely position sprites, have a look at [CocosBuilder](http://cocosbuilder.com/).